# Normalize json data per level

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm struggling to normalize json files that I'm importing from coinmarketcap.com. [Here's one of the json files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltBYT608E75L59KxVJdXMJDQ3F3Yg837/view?usp=sharinghttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltBYT608E75L59KxVJdXMJDQ3F3Yg837/view?usp=sharing), in case you'd like to check it.

If I understood how to use [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) correctly, I need to specifically point the indexes:values (using the index name) that I want to transform into columns:values. But in this case, the second level is a variable - the name of the asset/crypto - and it changes at each new block of data (the level's name changes for ex. among "BTC", "ETH", "LTC" etc). However, the following levels (the ones within each asset) have the same structure, so I'd like to normalize them within a single relevant column rather than creating different columns just because the second level (asset name) is different.

```
"status": {
    "timestamp": "2020-08-25T22:24:16.060Z",
    "error_code": 0,
},
"data": {
    "BTC": {
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "max_supply": 21000000,
         "quote": {
            "EUR": {
                "price": 9623.527026340924,
                "volume_24h": 21958302582.89148
            }
        }
    },
    "ETH": {
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "max_supply": null,
        "quote": {
            "EUR": {
                "price": 324.44292007109146,
                "volume_24h": 10492469772.346445,
            }
        }
    }
```

So from the example above, I want to create a dataframe that has a single column "symbol", a single column "price" (ideally "EUR-PRICE"), etc - and the respective value from each asset is in that same relevant column (and then I'll have a column with the asset name to be able to distinguish them).

```
ASSET - SYMBOL - EUR-PRICE 
BTC - BTC - 999,99
ETH - ETH - 888,88
```

But if I try `df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)`, I end up with a df  that has a single row, every field becoming a entire column per itself. And to be able to specify "paths" - i.e. `pandas.json_normalize(data, record_path)` - I'm required to define a specific second level name, rather than being able to use dynamical variables (the different asset names).

Any help will be highly appreciated. In particular, is there any way to define which values to add to a certain column based on their level-position within the json data?
(hope the question is not too confuse)

Answer (score 1):

1. turn `dict` into a `list` using a comprehension
2. two times `json_normalize()` exploding list on first pass

Results in data frame of 5 rows and 33 columns

```
import json

with open("cmc_test_file.json") as f: d = json.load(f)
d["data"] = [d["data"][k] for k in d["data"].keys()]
pd.json_normalize(pd.json_normalize(d).explode("data").to_dict(orient="records"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Rob, and I'm sorry for getting back to you. It worked nicely :-)